# Rodin tool prover - transitivity

Tags: formal-methods, event-b

So I'm getting to know the event-b specification language and the Rodin tool.

While doing that, I came across some weird behavior of the Rodin tool, and I'd love to get some help here.

I'm on the proving perspective, and I have two hypotheses:

- 1 <= v
- v <= n

my goal is:

- 1 <= n

I'd expect that the default auto prover will manage to handle it, but it is not.

My question is, should I configure something explicitly? Or maybe for some reason, this is not supposed to be discharged automatically?

The thing is that I can't even discharge it manually, since it's basic math.

[Thats how it looks in the Rodin tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C1Qb.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plug-in to use SMT solvers in proofs from within Rodin. There is also a plug-in to use Atelier B provers. You may want to try one of those.